# ExcelStyles in ag-grid version 18.1 not working for production build

Tags: angular, ag-grid

We have requirement to export preceding zeroes in excel. We followed ag-grid documentation 
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-excel/#example-export-with-styles
Functionality works correctly on localhost however it doesn't work when deployed server
We are using ag-grid angular version 18.1

Component Code

```
    export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-app';
  exStyles = [{
    id: 'textFormat',
    dataType: 'string'
  }];

  columnDefs = [
      {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make' },
      {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model' },
      {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price', cellClass: 'textFormat'}
  ];

  rowData = [
      { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: '0035000' },
      { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: '0032000' },
      { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: '0072000' }
  ];
}
```

Template Code

```
<ag-grid-angular
    style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [excelStyles]="exStyles"
    >
```

Comment: hard to provide solution without looking at your code. Can you post the code?

Comment: @PratikBhat Added Code

Comment: Your code looks correct to me

Comment: I was able to resolve issue. Updated build-angular version to 0.8.9